# What is the cost incurred in relation to setting an identity on Polkadot?

Tags: identity, pallet-identity, kilt

Based on the Polkadot wiki: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-identity
the cost of setting an identity is as follows: "Users must reserve funds in a bond to store their information on chain: 20.258 DOT and 0.066 DOT per each field beyond the legal name.". Additionally there is an additional layer (Judgments) where the users can pick registrars and an additional cost is associated with this.

- Typically, do the parachains initially have to incur these costs to onboard the Users? This is relevant for us as we budget out different costs for our network going forward.
- Additionally is it mandatory to implement the judgement process (because we are integrating with Kilt DID)?

Answer (score 1):

Judgements essentially is a business model on Polkadot that all different types of parties can provide the service for a fee. You could even provide your own judgement service.

The Web3 Foundation has a judgement service as well:
https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181990-how-to-request-and-cancel-identity-judgement

"The W3F registrar service is currently free to use on Polkadot, however on Kusama it requires a small fee of 0.04 KSM, which can be entered in the "maxFee" field as a value in Plancks, i.e. 40,000,000,000."

In the context of using Kilt, judgements is not totally necessary - it is mainly if the users want to link their Kilt DID with their Polkadot account identity: https://docs.kilt.io/docs/develop/sdk/cookbook/account_linking/account-link

This is for users who want their name/website etc on their Polkadot account identity to be tied to additional credentials on Kilt. Also this is not your cost, it is the user's cost to pay for judgements. Kilt has similar types of credential issuance that have services used for verification: https://docs.kilt.io/docs/develop/sdk/cookbook/public_credentials/public-credential-issuance

Ultimately this means it depends on who your target audience is and do they care if they want their identities linked to achieve your team's use case?